# Enabling openssl module after successful instillation

Tags: php, macos, macports, php-openssl

I am trying to enable openssl encryption for php 8.2 using macports so that I can use composer to download the required php libraries for google api's.

I'm attempting to install the required php libraries for running google api's via composer, however when I run the command 'php composer.phar require google/apiclient' I get the error message:
"In Factory.php line 648:
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true."

I use macports as I am currently running MacOS Catalina, which I used to download the current version of PHP and OpenSSL. They show to be installed when I check. When I look at the list of active modules in PHP with 'php -m' openssl does not show up. I have tried uncommenting the specific line of the php.ini file, like most guides say to, however there are two- developer and production (I used production) and no file extension on the line "extension=openssl" and in fact every line of the entire document begins with a semi-colon...
I tried disabling tsl, that didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: clearly I have done plenty of research as no current solution posted anywhere actually works, thanks for being a prick, whoever

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone having the same problem, while openssl was installed in the root directory, it was not installed in php.
sudo port install php82-openssl